# How to transfer apps from iPad to MacBook Pro

Tags: itunes, ipad, macbook-pro, data-transfer

I got a new MacBook Pro recently and I want to transfer my old apps into my new Mac, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

1. **Menubar -> Store -> Sign In** (with same account used on the iPad)
2. **Menubar -> iTunes -> Preferences -> Store -> Automatic Downloads**

Once you have signed in with your account, a sync via USB should do the trick aswell, I think.

BTW: You might also need to authorize your computer to play some purchased music (Menubar -> Store -> Authorize this computer)